Ordering symbolic equation output
I am a newbie to Mathematica and this is my first question on this forum. Thus, I will excuse myself in advance if I am asking a trivial question or if I am not following the correct practices.
Given this due disclaimer, onto my actual question: I am solving an octic even polynomial
$f(m, \alpha ) = 0$ to obtain the roots $m_i (\alpha)$ with $i = 1,...,8$. For reference, I am solving this polynomial by substituting $p(\alpha) = (m(\alpha))^2 - \alpha^2$ and then solving the resulting quartic $q(p,\alpha) = 0$. Lastly, I compute $m(\alpha) = \pm \sqrt{p(\alpha)}$. $f,q$ have real coefficients, $\alpha \in [-\infty, \infty]$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $m_j \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I need to order these eight roots $m_i$ to perform further calculations based on the conditions:
$$ \begin{cases}  \Re(m_i) <0 &\\m_{i+4} = - m_i & \text{ with } i \in [1,2,3,4]\\ \end{cases} $$
I am struggling to understand whether:

It's possible to order the roots while leaving them as a function of $\alpha$
How to perform such task in Mathematica

1st edit:
(* Charachteristic equation for the shell*)
chPoly = 
  m^8 - 4 m^2 \[Alpha]^6 + \[Alpha]^8 - 
   m^6 (4 \[Alpha]^2 + \[Kappa] \[Lambda]2^4) + 
   m^4 (6 \[Alpha]^4 + \[Lambda]2^4 + \[Alpha]^2 \[Kappa] \
\[Lambda]2^4);
(* change of variable to obtain a quartic p = m^2 - \[Alpha]^2*)
Quartic = Simplify[Expand[chPoly /. m -> Sqrt[p + \[Alpha]^2]]];
(* solve the quartic *)
ps = SolveValues[Quartic == 0, p];
(* get the squared roots *)
msSquared = ps + \[Alpha]^2;
(* get the roots *)
ms =  Flatten[{-1 Sqrt[msSquared], Sqrt[msSquared]}];
(* TODO: order the roots*)

2nd edit: I changed the roots[] to SolveValues[] and changed the Sqrt[msSquared] to  Flatten[{-1 Sqrt[msSquared], Sqrt[msSquared]}] to get all 8 expected solutions.

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please present Mathematica code for a minimal example (or what you have tried so far). Is your first condition in conflict with the second one?

The conditions are not in conflict. I added the minimal working example

Roots returns equations not values.

@DanielHuber thanks for pointing that out. I updated the question. Now I hope it's possible to answer to my question

Are you sure that the order does not depend on alpha?

I know that asymptotically the roots are linear with its modulus (i.e., $m \propto | \alpha |$ for  $| \alpha | \to \infty $). My idea was to simply check that if $\partial_{\alpha} m_j < 0$ and $\Re (m_j(\alpha = 0)) < 0$, then I can use $m_j$. And repeat that for $j = 1,2,3,4$
